# Google Compute Cloud Network Balancer not working

Tags: google-compute-engine

I configured a network balancer for my two instances and the port range of 8080-8080 (tcp:8080). The zone is correct, my instances are in us-central1-f and my network balancer is configured for us-central1.

However, when I try to curl to the network forward rule IP it does not properly route to any of the instances.

The health check on the pool of instances shows that both instances are good. And I can curl to each instances directly.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I can curl the network forward rule IP from the instances in the pool, but not from any other instance. For example my instance in the load balance pool 10.240.0.1 is running a web server. My network balancer ip is 10.10.1.1 If I I ssh into 10.240.0.1 and then curl 10.10.1.1:8080 everything works fine. If I ssh into any other instance (not in the network load balance pool) and try to curl 10.10.1.1:8080, then no response.

Comment: So I figured out that I have a firewall rule that only allows traffic to port 8080 from internal IPs 10.240.0.0/16 I do this so my instances can only be accessed via VPN (which I have set up and running on another VM) however since the network load balancer IP is an external IP (not one on the 10.240.0.0/16 range) firewall prevents the network balancer to work

Comment: So the question is, is it possible to define a network load balance rule with an internal IP, not with an external ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old and i don't think I have this issue anymore so I'm just going to attribute this issue to the "ghost in the machine"